# Directory.GetFiles vs. ListDatasets - Which is the tool for the job?

Tags: arcobjects, c#, .net

I'm currently writing an arcobjects app that performs an arbitrary set of geoprocessing tasks on a group of shapefiles and/or dbf tables. My current implementation uses Directory.GetFiles to build an array of file paths which I feed to various GP execution functions. I'm wondering if ListDatasets can perform the same task. I need to search an entire directory tree starting at a given root folder for all files which match a given search string. I am not certain if ListDatasets will do this (I have a devil of a time deciphering the SDK documentation).

In short, which would prove more efficient and effective and recursively searching a directory tree for .shp and .dbf files, `Directory.GetFiles`, `GP.ListDatasets`, or some heretofore unmentioned method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would imagine using the built-in C# methods would be faster for using recursively, but of course you could only do it with files, not geodatabase feature classes/tables. Here's an example of a recursive file/directory processor: [Directory.GetDirectories](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1sez4sc%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

If going the ArcObjects route I would look at the help topic "[How to list data](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//000100000223000000)", which has all the keywords expected. Looks like you would want to use a combination of `ListTables` and `ListFeatureClasses`, and `ListWorkspaces` to recurse folder workspaces. Use `ListDatasets` if you are in a geodatabase and need to look in Feature Datasets.

If speed is not critical I would probably use the ArcObjects methods especially if there was a chance I would ever want to use geodatabases. I think they also check that each file they come upon is valid, i.e. they won't list shapefiles that are missing a critical file, or a file that happens to have a .shp extension but isn't actually a shapefile.

You could always do both and time it yourself.

Comment: I think another concern I'm having is that ListDatasets will not return tables as well as shapefiles. I am not sure that I understand the method properly, though. Will ListDatasets return shp and dbf, or is it only for finding workspaces like gdbs?

Comment: Added some more info to the answer, hopefully that helps. ListDatasets only returns Feature Datasets and a few other dataset types like TINs.